# How to close the VBE extension in QEMU

Tags: c, operating-system, qemu

I use init function to use the VBE extension, however, I cannot close it.

```
uint16_t qemu_vga_init(uint16_t xres, uint16_t yres, uint16_t bpp) {
    if(0 == qemu_vga_addr) return FAIL;

    old_vga_enable = qemu_vga_read(QEMU_VGA_IDX_ENABLE);

    old_vga_idx_xres = qemu_vga_read(QEMU_VGA_IDX_XRES);
    old_vga_idx_yres = qemu_vga_read(QEMU_VGA_IDX_YRES);
    old_vga_idx_bpp = qemu_vga_read(QEMU_VGA_IDX_BPP);
    old_vga_idx_vw = qemu_vga_read(QEMU_VGA_IDX_VIRT_WIDTH);
    old_vga_idx_x_offset = qemu_vga_read(QEMU_VGA_IDX_X_OFFSET);
    old_vga_idx_y_offset = qemu_vga_read(QEMU_VGA_IDX_Y_OFFSET);
    old_vga_cur_id = qemu_vga_read(QEMU_VGA_IDX_ID);

    // Check if QEMU VGA device is present, and version correct
    qemu_vga_write(QEMU_VGA_IDX_ID, QEMU_VGA_MAX_VER);
    uint16_t ver = qemu_vga_read(QEMU_VGA_IDX_ID);

    if(ver < QEMU_VGA_MIN_VER || ver > QEMU_VGA_MAX_VER) {
        return FAIL;
    }

    // Currently only supports 16 bit and 32 bit BPP.
    // No plan to add more support as we don't use them.
    if(bpp != 16 && bpp != 32) return FAIL;

    // Store state information for later address calculation
    qemu_vga_xres = xres;
    qemu_vga_yres = yres;
    qemu_vga_bpp = bpp;

    // Write the setting into VGA
    qemu_vga_write(QEMU_VGA_IDX_ENABLE, 0);

    qemu_vga_write(QEMU_VGA_IDX_ENABLE, 1);

    qemu_vga_write(QEMU_VGA_IDX_ENABLE, 0);  


    qemu_vga_write(QEMU_VGA_IDX_XRES, xres);
    qemu_vga_write(QEMU_VGA_IDX_YRES, yres);
    qemu_vga_write(QEMU_VGA_IDX_BPP, bpp);
    qemu_vga_write(QEMU_VGA_IDX_VIRT_WIDTH, xres);
    qemu_vga_write(QEMU_VGA_IDX_X_OFFSET, 0);
    qemu_vga_write(QEMU_VGA_IDX_Y_OFFSET, 0);
    qemu_vga_enabled = 1;

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

The close mean software close, because I need also to reopen it. Thanks.

Comment: This code isn't using the VBE extension (it's using an internal hack developed by Qemu & Bochs developers to make it easier/faster for their firmware to implement VBE/VESA BIOS extensions by shoving most of the work directly into the emulated VGA hardware). It's also not "opening" anything (and can't be closed) - I think what you want is to restore the video hardware to a previous state or set it to a specific state (possibly a "80*25 text mode with 16 colors" state). In other words, you want to do a second video mode switch (to cancel/revert the first video mode switch).

Comment: Also note that the code that should be using the "internal hack" (the firmware/VGA ROM that implements VBE) is open source and available at http://www.nongnu.org/vgabios/ . You should be able to use ROM's source code to determine how it does what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, I intend to do the next video mode switch so that I can recover the text mode. Do you have any ideas about this part? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for the "VBE, Set Video Mode" function starting at line 986 in `vgabios/vbe.c` (which can be accessed as HTML at http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/vgabios/trunk/vgabios/vbe.c?revision=253&view=markup ); you can see that if the caller is using VBE to switch back to a legacy VGA video mode the code just calls `biosfn_set_video_mode()`, which is the same function that would've been called by the legacy VGA "set mode" (`int 0x13, ah = 0x00` in real mode).

The `biosfn_set_video_mode()` starts at line 810 in `vgabios/vgabios.c` (which can be accessed as HTML at http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/vgabios/trunk/vgabios/vgabios.c?revision=256&view=markup ). This code is configuring raw VGA registers (and isn't using the "internal hack to make VBE easier to implement"). This is much messier (and not just because it's not cheating) - VGA has awful "video memory planes", and indexed palettes, and fonts that need to be uploaded (and VBE/higher resolution modes doesn't have any of that mess).

You'll have to go through this code one line at a time porting `biosfn_set_video_mode()` (and anything it calls, tables it uses, etc) to your code. If you only care about a specific video mode (e.g. the "80x25 with 16-colour" mode) you will be able to skip parts (e.g. the part to setup the DAC used for the 256-color mode) and use constants instead of a "video mode info table"; but it will still be a time consuming and error prone task.

NOTE: I would very much recommend writing code that works on real computers (that also works on Qemu) by using the VBE and VGA BIOS functions themselves; and forgetting about writing code to abuse Qemu's internal hackery (for setting a high resolution video mode) and Qemu's specific implementation/emulation of a 1980s VGA card. Depending on your goals; often (if it's something like an OS that doesn't want to/shouldn't use BIOS functions after boot) the best approach is to set the best possible video mode once during boot (and then write code that generates pixel data/graphics for a high resolution video mode that mimics the appearance of a clunky/ugly VGA text mode without actually using a clunky/ugly VGA text mode).